Difference between the weak and weak* topology (using seminorms to define the topologies)
A few days ago, I was interested in the weak topology and the fact that the weak topology is the coarsest topology such that $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ is continuous.
(How to show that, the weak topology is the coarsest topology such that all $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ are continuous?)
Now, I would like to consider the weak* topology.
Definition (weak* topology)
So suppose $X$ is a normed space.
Define $p_x^*:X^* \rightarrow [0,\infty)$, where $p_x^*(f):=|f(x)|$. Consider the family of seminorms $ \mathcal{P}^*:=\{p_x^* | x \in X\}$.
The topology induced by $\mathcal{P}^*$ is called the weak* topology. Now I want to show that the weak* topology is the coarsest topology such that $f \mapsto f(x)$ is continuous, where $f \in X^*$.
Now I am a little bit confused about the weak* topology.
Lets $\tau_{\mathcal{P}^*}$ denote the topology induced by $\mathcal{P}^*$.
As far as I understand it, I have to show that if tehre is a topology $\tau$ such that all $f \in X^*$ are continuous, then $\tau_{\mathcal{P}^*} \subseteq \tau$.
This seems very similar to what i did in the case of the weak topology, but with the difference in case of the weak topology the family of seminorms $\mathcal{P}$ was defined by using $X^*$ as "index set", whereas in the case of the weak* topology the family of seminorms $\mathcal{P}^*$ is indexed by $X$.
Now I am confused on the difference between the weak and weak* topology. Further, I don't even know what I have to do, to show that the weak* is the coarsest topology. (It should be a similar argument, but the fact that $\mathcal{P}^*$ is indexed by $X$ kind of sets me off).
